# Sharing Python object in multiprocessing: Value or Manager

Tags: python, multiprocessing

If I want to share an object using [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html), 
which of the following should I use depending on what circumstances?

- [multiprocessing.Value](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Value) or `multiprocessing.Array`
- or [multiprocessing.Manager](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#managers)

it seems to me that:

- `Value` only works for object of `ctypes` (but what's `ctypes`? are `numpy.ndarray` `ctypes` or `networkx.Graph`)
- `Manager` can be used for arbitrary Python object, but I need to wrap the object methods

Please help correct my understanding. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`Value` is scalar it can hold only one single data time. Therefore, if you want to share say `char`, `double`, `int`, or `float` between different processes you should use `Array`. Unlike `Value`, `Array` can hold multiple values.

For an extensive list of `ctypes` as defined in Python's `ctypes`: have a look at this documentation: [Fundamental data types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#fundamental-data-types). Therefore, `int`, `bool`, `long`, `short` and many others are datatypes in the C programming language.

For a `Manager` object, I think the documentation is extensive on that:

> Managers provide a way to create data which can be shared between different processes, including sharing over a network between processes running on different machines. A manager object controls a server process which manages shared objects. Other processes can access the shared objects by using proxies.

You might be wondering what this is all about! You just have to play with code to see how all that fits together, its not that complicated.